# Is the following integral convergent?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Is $\int_0^{\infty}(1-e^{-x})\frac{\cos x}{x}$ dx convergent? Any help will be very helpful. I tried to use comparison test with bounding $\cos x$ by 1 and $(1-e^{-x})$ by 1 and so on but the series to which i tried to compare became divergent so I was unable to conclude any further.

Comment: Yes, and the value is $\ln(2)/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Near zero, the integrand is
$$(x+O(x^2))\frac{\cos x}x$$
so the integral converges there.

At infinity the integral of $x^{-1}\cos x$ converges conditionally
(compare $x^{-1}\sin x$) and that of  $e^{-x}x^{-1}\cos x$ converges
absolutely.

The answer is then, yes.